# ボタンクリック後、プログレスバーが処理中に動きません。処理後に動きます。

Tags: python, tkinter

Raspberry Pi上にPythonでコーディングしています。GUIにはtkinterを使っています。
以下のプログラムを作る予定です。

まずstartボタンをクリックすると、ボタンのtextがstartからstopに変わり、ボタンの下に「please wait」が表示され、I2cセンサから情報を取り込みを開始します。この間、プログレスバーが起動します。センサから情報取得が完了したら、プログレスバーが停止し、ボタンのtextがｓtopからstartに変わり、ボタンの下の「please wait」表示が消えます。

ところが、以下のソースを書いたところ、startボタンをクリックすると、プログレスバーは起動せず、センサから情報取得が完了してから起動します。ボタンのtextがstartからstopに変わり、ボタンの下に「please wait」が表示されるのもセンサからの情報取得完了後です。センサから情報を取得するのに時間がかかるので(２～３分)、ユーザーが使いやすいようにプログレスバーを貼ったのですが、うまくいきません。

ボタンクリック後、センサから情報を取得する処理中にプログレスバーを稼働させたいのですが、よろしければアドバイスをお願いします。

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import max30102n

def start_click():
    if button0["text"] == "start":
        button0["text"] = "stop"
        label0["text"] = "please,wait"
        pb.start(100)
        m = max30102n.MAX30102()
        red, ir = m.read_sequential(150)

    else:
        button0["text"] = "start"
        label0["text"] = ""
        pb.stop()

def stop_click():
    label0["text"] = ""
    pb.stop()
    canvas0.delete('line0')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('progrss bar')
root.geometry('800x600')
#style = ttk.Style()

frame0 = tk.Frame(root)
frame0.grid()

canvas0 = tk.Canvas(frame0, bg='White', width=760, height=160)
canvas0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=10, pady=10)
canvas0.create_line(0, 80, 760, 80, fill='red')

button0 = tk.Button(frame0, text='start', width=10, command=start_click)
button0.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=30)

label0 = tk.Label(frame0)
label0.grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)
pb = ttk.Progressbar(frame0, length=760, mode='indeterminate')
#pb = ttk.Progressbar(frame0, length=760, mode='determinate', variable=global_num)
pb.grid(row=3,column=0, columnspan=6, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: こちらに英語版。[the progressbar don't move during other processing in python on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61604904/9014308) スレッドを作ったり`after`でインターバル処理にしたりして、並行処理しないと目的のものは作れないでしょう。[Python3 tkinter whileループを開始するとボタンが押せなくなる](https://teratail.com/questions/147384), [Python3のtkinterで並行処理？を行いたい](https://teratail.com/questions/147319), [簡易ストップウォッチを作ってみた　＠Python3](https://i94025.at.webry.info/201301/article_3.html), [【Python】Tkinterで作るGUIアプリ「個人的よく使うまとめ」](https://qiita.com/michimichix521/items/3e07f6b04174e1b38fbf)

Comment: `m.read_sequential(150)`が取得処理なのでしょうが、並行処理が出来たとしても、定期的にコールバック処理が呼ばれるとか、何かのプロパティで作業状況がシェアされて見えるとかでない限り、プログレスバーに表示する情報が無いのでは？ 単純に処理時間は固定的に決まっていて、時間経過で表示出来るというのであれば別ですが。 この辺の記事が関連でしょうか。[max30102/max30102.py](https://github.com/doug-burrell/max30102/blob/master/max30102.py), [Raspberry Piと心拍センサ(MAX30102)で脈を見てみよう](https://qiita.com/vrn/items/1ac58c61194b23af1d8c), [心拍・酸素飽和度モニタモジュール MAXREFDES117#](https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/3208/), [MAXREFDES117#: Heart-Rate and Pulse-Oximetry Monitor](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/reference-design-center/system-board/6300.html/tb_tab2)

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。並列処理（Threading)を用い、プログラムを書き直したところ、自己解決しました。今後とも、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 特定のハード環境が無いと確認しにくいものなので、解決したなら自己回答で情報共有をお願いします。

Comment: 参考にしたサイトのリンクを貼っておきます。「foo()」以下にセンサを動かす処理を書き込んだところ、正常動作しました。https://ja.coder.work/so/python/1200710